# Test if \author{} macro is empty

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I have to check if the `\author{}` macro is empty because the output should change if this condition is set.

There are two ways the author can be empty:

- `\author{}`
- No `\author{}` command in the document.

---

I tried with the `\ifdefempty{\macro}{<true>}{<false>}` command of `etoolbox`, which works fine for self defined macros like `\def\testmacro{foo}`, but for `\author` it always results on `false`.

How could I test if an author is set and then modify the output based on the result of this check? (The check should work as the `\ifdefempty` command)

Comment: The `\author{Me}` command essentially does `\def\@author{Me}`, so you need to test `\@author` for emptiness. Beware that some classes initialize `\@author` to be something else than empty.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but if I set `\author{}`, nothing is printed, even though `\@author` is probably not empty (as it also evaluates as false). I want to check if there is a content that is also printed on the page.

Comment: Indeed, in the standard classes `\@author` is not initialized to empty.

Comment: put `\show\@author` then tex will stop (as for an error) and show you what the initial definition is with the class you are using

Comment: @egreg No I didn't use the `\makeat*` commands. I now tried with them and it works, so could you please tell me what those do? I never got it. They seem to be pretty important.

Comment: They just allow you to use the `@` character in the document so you can access the `\@author` command (the idea being that this is a special command that  would normally only be used in a class or package file).

Comment: @Sam See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/)

Answer (score 8):

If you redefine the user command `\author` and the internal command `\@author`, you can make them do what you want them to. You can set them up in a way that you can test. A simple example is below, explained in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter % make it safe to use \@author

% Make \author do what you want it to: set a value for \@author
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\def\@author{#1}}

% Create a test for whether author is present (non-empty)
\newif\ifauthor
\authorfalse % Set default value of conditional to false
\def\@author{} % Set default value of \@author to empty

% Create a command to check if \@author is empty and set the
% \ifauthor conditional accordingly, for use in other commands
\newcommand{\authorcheck}{%
    \ifx\@author\empty
    \authorfalse
    \else
    \authortrue
    \fi
}

% A sample command that would use this value to print the author, 
% if non-empty, or "Anonymous" instead
\newcommand{\printauthor}{%
    \authorcheck
    AUTHOR: \ifauthor\@author\else Anonymous\fi\par
}
\makeatother % We're done using @ now

% \author{Me} % Uncomment to test
\title{This}

\begin{document}
\printauthor
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer.  For anyone using their own .cls file, everything above % \author{Me} can be put in the .cls file.  Make sure to still call the \printauthor somewhere in the .tex file to cause \authorcheck to run, otherwise \ifauthor will remain false.